# Sql Trigger not creating properly

Tags: triggers

I am also creating the trigger but it aslo does not work

After creating this trigger i can not insert any borrow recorde.. But I want to make the trigger so that I can not insert the burrow record in December.

Comment: Hi, to improve your chances of getting an answer, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ok .sorry i noted it